# How to convert symbols into ASCII (hex or dec) in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, dremel

URLs aren't translating. For ex. & needs to be translated in to %26 in order for the auto-generated url to populate data in a dashboard. I've tried `cast`, `convert` and `to_code_points` but all to no avail.

Comment: What SQL are you using - many will not support HTML character translations inherently. You probably want to look at the string functions for your version of SQL and see if it support str_replace

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: There is a solution here for you.

Comment: What do you mean by "run properly"? Why should a database be concerned with url encoding? Both `&` and `%26` use plain ASCII characters

Comment: I'm using BigQuery. The auto-generated URLs are linked to a dashboard. The URL that has the ampersand (&) is displaying a dashboard that is empty when I know there's data in the dashboard. So that is why I want to convert the URL into a series of % and hex digits. Hope this further explains my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use REPLACE (or it's equivalent), for instance:

```
select replace(@url_string, '&', '%26')
```

You can nest them to do multiple replacements, like this:

```
select replace(replace(@url_string, ' ', '%20'), '&', '%26')
```

For example:

```
select replace(replace('qwe&qwe&asd zxc zxc', ' ', '%20'), '&', '%26')
```

gives:

```
'qwe%26qwe%26asd%20zxc%20zxc'
```

I did this using SQL Server but any other SQL database will have a function that is very similar if not identical.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think this will work. Thanks so much! Hopefully I'm not going to have many other characters to replace.

Comment: You're welcome @S.R. - Please mark my answer as 'Accepted' if it helped you.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Dump() function will give you the characters encoded into one of a number of encodings e.g. decimal or hex